# Code works for upto certain point then crashes

Tags: c++, debugging

The following code is for finding 2^n. It works fine (and gives the correct result) for n<=1307. However it crashes for n>1307. I would like to know where the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
const int n=1307;                  //digit sum of 2^n
const int digit= n*log10(2)+5;     //expected no of digits in 2^n (+5 for safety)

int main()
{
    int power[n][digit];    // power[n][k] is the kth digit (from right) of 2^n
    for (int iii=0; iii<=n; iii++)          // initialize every digit to 0
        for (int jjj=0; jjj<digit; jjj++)
            power[iii][jjj]=0;
    power[1][0]=2;                          //set 2^1=2

        //each step calculate 2^n by doubling 2^(n-1)

    for (int iii=2; iii<=n; iii++)
    {
        int carry=0;
        for (int jjj=0; jjj<digit; jjj++)
        {
            int k=2*power[iii-1][jjj];      //temp variable
            power[iii][jjj]=(k+carry)%10;
            carry=(k+carry)/10;
        }
    }


    for (int jjj=digit -1; jjj>=0; jjj--)
        cout << power[n][jjj];
}
```

There shouldn't be any problems concerning types (int, long), only single digit calculations are taking place. So, where's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: I did, first it returned no problem. Then I noticed I only ran it for n<=1307. Ran it again with n=1308, returned fragmentation fault. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: you are probably nuking the stack. try allocating `power` via `malloc` or `new`

Comment: @Valerji, Could you explain what you mean by "nuking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it in a debugger. Moreover, you set

```
int power[n][digit];
```

but your loop does

```
for(int iii=0;iii<=n;++iii)
```

Index out of bounds when iii = n.

Comment: Good point. Arises another interesting fact. Instead of int power[n][digit], used int power[n+1][digit], now the program breaks down at n=1307. Then I experimented further, used n+2 instead of n+1, then the program breaks down at n=1306. But at n+3, it again broke at 1306 (not 1305). At last did something completely crazy, used int power[1][digit], Guess what!! the code is fixed, it doesn't crash for high values of n such as 100000. Though we don't get any results probably due to high calculation times. But most interestingly when it does give a result, IT STILL GIVES CORRECT RESULTS.

Comment: And for debuggers, It returned fragmentation fault.